# Downgrade versão de projeto no android studio de 6.0 para 5.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Desenvolvi um projeto no android studio na **API 23: Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)**. 
No entanto, o projeto deveria ser desenvolvido para android 5.0.
Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de fazer algum tipo de downgrade para a versão **API 21: Android 5.0 (Lollipop)** no android studio?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.eng.itech.execamera_2019101"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Desenvolvi um projeto no android studio na API 23: Android 6.0 (Marshmallow).

Não, o projecto foi desenvolvido usando a API 28 como indicado no *build.gradle* com `compileSdkVersion 28`.

> Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de fazer algum tipo de downgrade para a versão API 21: Android 5.0 (Lollipop)

Não sei exactamente o que pretende ou o porquê de fazer "downgrade". Qualquer que seja a razão tenha em conta o seguinte:

- Deve compilar sempre a aplicação usando a versão mais recente da API. Assim poderá utilizar todos os recursos do SDK, incluindo os novos que não existem em versões anteriores.
  Deve indicá-la no *build.gradle* em `compileSdkVersion version`.
- Onde a sua aplicação pode rodar, depende do que foi informado no *build.gradle* em `defaultConfig`(equivalente á *tag* [`<uses-sdk>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) no *AndroidManifest.xml*).

  Ela tem três atributos:

  - android:minSdkVersion="integer"
  - android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
  - android:maxSdkVersion="integer"

  Esses três atributos permitem à aplicação informar a sua compatibilidade com uma ou mais versões do Android.

  O seu significado é o seguinte:

  - **android:minSdkVersion="integer"** - Indica o nível mínimo da API requerido para a aplicação correr. O Android não deixará que a aplicação seja instalada em dispositivos com um nível da API inferior ao valor indicado por este atributo.
  - **android:targetSdkVersion="integer"** - Indica o nível da API para o qual a aplicação foi feita.
    Informa o sistema que a aplicação foi testada para correr nesse nível e o sistema não deverá disponibilizar qualquer tipo de "comportamento de compatibilidade" para a executar em dispositivos com nível de API igual.
  - **android:maxSdkVersion="integer"** - Indica o nível máximo da API em que a aplicação pode correr.
    O Android não permitirá que a aplicação seja instalada em dispositivos com um nível da API superior ao valor indicado neste atributo.

    **Atenção:** A declaração deste atributo não é recomendada, as novas versões da API são desenhadas para serem compativeis com as versões anteriores. Não há razão para intensionalmente bloquear a possibilidade da aplicação ser instalada em novas versões.

Comment: Creio que ele apenas não esteja conseguindo rodar o app no android 5 por causa do `minSdkVersion 23`, se ele alterar para 21 acho que ja chega onde ele quer

Comment: @BrunoRomualdo É possível que seja por isso que o AP diz querer fazer "downgrade", não sei. No entanto uma resposta mais abrangente e explicativa é mais útil.

Comment: Exatamente! A grande questão é que o aplicativo roda perfeitamente nos dispositivos com versão 6.0 ou superior. No entanto, os usuários que ainda possuem dispositivos com android 5.0 não conseguem instalar o aplicativo. Por esse motivo, gostaria de fazer o ""downgrade" da versão que desenvolvi para 5.0. Caso isso não seja possível, vou ter que desenvolver o projeto todo novamente na versão 5.0!?

Answer (score 1):

Mude o `minSdkVersion 23` para 21.